# How to update ObservableCollection in UI?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection

```
foreach (var t in ((App)App.Current).CollectionMessages)
  if (t.Uid.ToString() == uid)
    t.TexT = z;
```

The item in CollectionMessages, filed TexT changes Text to what I want. But the UI has no changes, it shows old value. What's wrong?Please help me.

Xaml:

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Диалоги" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
    </StackPanel>
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox" >
                    <ListBox  x:Name="mess_list"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TexT}" " />
```

...

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that the class of which `t` is a type implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), and fires the `PropertyChanged` event when you set `TexT`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and raise a property changed event so that the UI knows it has to update.

This [How to:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) page has a worked example. You basically need this code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

which gets called when the things you want to update get changed. So the code for `TexT` becomes:

```
private string localTexT
public string TexT
{
    get { return localTexT; }
    set
    {
        localTexT = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TexT");
    }
}
```

From your update it looks like you've got the binding of the `ItemsSource` and `TextBlock` correct. However, have you set the `DataContext` of the view?

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged was fired but nothing in UI was changed.

Comment: @wsevendays - Would need to see the XAML. Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Not, I'm using ItemsSource property.

Comment: @wsevendays - edit the XAML into your question. It will help to see how the binding's defined.

Comment: Check my edit. And also CollectionMessages is ObservableCollection

Comment: hmm..I never set this, my code works without it before this time. full code : http://pastebin.com/gurMVfKi